# Как избежать тавтологии (время) и нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, тавтология

> Затворницы уделяют своё время уединению и размышлению, оттого время от
>   времени монастырь даже закрывается, как пишут сёстры на тяжелых
>   воротах своего неприступного замка – *на уединение*.

Курсив автора.

---

, как пишут сёстры на тяжелых воротах своего неприступного замка,

монастырь закрывается – на уединение.

Comment: "Затворницы уделяют **своё** время уединению и размышлению" --- Как вы это понимаете: уделяют все своё время или часть его? Формально — все свое время, в противном случае было бы без *свое*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуем ещё вариант. Возможно, подойдет:

Затворницы проводят свою жизнь в одиночестве и размышлениях, поэтому [или — потому] время от времени монастырь даже закрывается — *на уединение*. Именно так пишут сёстры на тяжелых воротах своего неприступного замка.

Comment: Римуль, ну всё не так! Они труженицы, а не паразитки! Мой вариант пока, имхо, лучший (по бережности к оригиналу): *Затворницы зачастую предаются уединению и размышлению, оттого время от времени монастырь даже закрывается, как пишут сёстры на тяжёлых воротах своего неприступного замка, – **на уединение***. Мне только *зачастую* как-то не в кайф.

Comment: Не нравится "зачастую"? Можно заменить на **нередко**.

Answer (score 1):

«Затворницы уделяют своё время уединению и размышлению, оттого время от времени монастырь даже закрывается, как пишут сёстры на тяжелых воротах своего неприступного замка – на уединение».

Затворницы проводят своё время уединённо, в размышлении, оттого по необходимости монастырь даже закрывается, как пишут сёстры на тяжелых воротах своего неприступного убежища — на уединение.

Answer (score 1):

**Проблемное предложение**: два повтора (время и уединение), "уделяют свое время" - не очень корректно, смысл высказывания обозначен не чётко.

Поэтому (после долгих размышлений) могу предложить такой вариант:

**Жизнь затворниц должна проходить в одиночестве и размышлениях,  оттого время от времени монастырь даже закрывается "на уединение" — так пишут сёстры на тяжелых воротах своего неприступного замка.**

Кстати, запятая нужна, что тоже не украшает заданное предложение.

Comment: "Должна" - нельзя, это рассказ о современных августинках, описываем как есть.Я нарисовала - с вопросом, конечно, - автору так: ***Затворницы зачастую предаются уединению и размышлению, оттого время от времени монастырь даже закрывается, как пишут сёстры на тяжёлых воротах своего неприступного замка, – на уединение.***

Comment: "Должна" - может относиться и к современным  августинкам. Как я понимаю текст, обязанность затворниц  - подолгу размышлять в одиночестве, чему, может быть, мешают посетители, вот тогда монастырь закрывается под этим предлогом  (что-то вроде выходных дней).